# Prove, for N as a whole number, n^2 is even if n is even.

Tags: formal-proofs

For the proof, "**prove for n as a whole number, n^2 is even if and only if n is even**", if we were to prove it via contradiction, would the negative of the statement which we need to contradict be:

"**n^2 is odd if and only if n is even**" or

"**n^2 is even if and only if n is odd**".

Comment: What is 'N' in your problem? I think it should also be 'n'.

Comment: Yep, sorry! It was meant to be 'n' I just edited it.

Comment: Neither. The negation would be: either there exists an $n $ where $n$ is even and $n^2$ is odd, or there exists an $n $ where $n $ is odd and $n^2$ is even.

Comment: Actually the negation of the statement should be "There exists an n so that $n^2$ is even and n is odd or so that n is even but $n^2$ is odd", I think....But the proof of the original pbm is very obvious that you don't need a contradiction  method

Comment: Yeah it is quite obvious! Its just that the question on the book says to solve via contradiction so I was confused how I'd start off.

Comment: Thanks anyways!

Comment: Seetha.  That is incorrect.  The negation is that there is at least one n where $n $ where $n and $n^2$ are different parity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negation would be: there is at least one $n $ where either $n^2$ is odd while $n $ is even or where $n $ is odd and $n^2$ is even.  All  other statements, yours, the other answer, and the comments are way too strong.  The negation requires only a single counter example.

Answer (score 0):

($n^2$ is even and $n$ is odd) or ($n^2$ is odd and $n$ is even)

Comment: But not nesc. for every n.  There may be only one such n for only one such property.

Comment: Right , However proof by contradiction is not recommended for this problem  ;prove the if part by induction and then the only if part by induction . If you were just interested in the logic for its own sake ,the above comments give the required result .

Answer (score 0):

The proof of your original statement....
If $n^2$ is even then 2|$n^2$. As 2 is prime, 2 |n. So n is even.
If n is even then $n^2$ is obviously even.
Hence your statement.